# git submodule init ignore failed

Tags: git, kohana

I just pulled https://github.com/kolanos/kohana-universe and now I'm trying to update all the modules running:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Some of the repos are wrong or not existent anymore, and the command breaks in the middle.

Is there an option for the command to ignore the failed updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i know is to remove broken submodule. This is how you can remove submodules - [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Ok! I'll accept your answer in a day or two if there's no other answers!

Answer (score 2):

From [this page](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/19933161.html) I've found a way to exclude a submodule from `submodule update`. Suppose the module is `dir/name`. Then the recursive update-init command for all submodules except this one will look like

```
git -c submodule.dir/name.update=none submodule update --init --recursive
```

This doesn't automate skipping any unforeseen errors, but works fine if you know that some particular submodule won't update.