# How to clone git repo with many git submodules, some of which are broken/missing?

Tags: git, git-submodules

For example,

```
git clone --depth 1 --recursive https://github.com/gohugoio/hugoThemes.git themes
```

You can try:

```
git submodule update --init
```

But basically this stops on the first errors. When you don't own the repo, you probably just want to skip the broken or private repos but I don't think git has a skip-errors option yet. A foreach command might solve but haven't discovered yet.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that it is not possible to ignore those errors - [git submodule init ignore failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886905/git-submodule-init-ignore-failed).
Unless, you could create some bash script, which will get list of submodules (not sure, if it is possible) -> and then updated them one-by-one.

Comment: Yes, that is what I see and have done in the past. Probably requires some thinking and discussion on the git forums then.